# Animating a double variable in Swift

Tags: c#, ios, animation

There's many code that show how to use View.animate to animate the properties of a view but none to animate a simple double variable.
I'm using CoreGraphic to draw some charts. Below the c# code to draw a bar:

```
var rectanglePath = UIBezierPath.FromRoundedRect(new CGRect(x,y,w,h*coef), corner);
color.SetFill();
rectanglePath.Fill();
```

I'm using a double (coef) that goes from 0 to 1 in the goal of having the bar growing but I don't find how to do. I tried using view.animate but it put the value to 1 in one frame when it works gradualy with alpha.

So what is the right way to do that ? (in swift or c# it's ok)

Answer (score 0):

The easiest thing to do would be to install the path in a custom UIView, and then use a UIView animation to animate the height of the view from 0 to full height (save the full height to a separate variable. Set the height to zero. Create an animation that animates the height back to it's original height.)_

You might need to use a height constraint rather than manipulating the frame.height of the view directly, since Auto-Layout makes animating a view's frame problematic.

Comment: This way the drawing will be disformed, this is why I'm using CoreGraphic

Answer (score 0):

I find a solution with timers (c#):

```
    TimerCallback timerDelegate = new TimerCallback(UpdateCG);
    timer = new Timer(timerDelegate,this, 0, 100);

    private void UpdateCG(object state)
    {
        coef+=(1-coef)/100;
        NSOperationQueue.MainQueue.AddOperation( ()=>{SetNeedsDisplay(); } );
    }
```